Obscure 1990s Fantasy book series about a male barbarian class warrior who can use shaman magic?
The main protagonist is a male barbarian class warrior who can use shamanic magic while using a red gem and had a relations with a harpy who bore him a rare male harpy son. I know this isn't much. The cover, I remember was yellow with the barbarian protagonist holding the magic red gem. This has been plaguing my memory for while. I also remember his gruff personality.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall how many books were in the series at the time you read it?

It's a bit of a long shot but perhaps The Demon Hand (1988) by Rose Estes?  It's the fifth book of a series set in the D&D world of Greyhawk.

Normally I'd go to the Internet Archive and look for a copy to mine for quotes, but since that's down I'll have to be satisfied with just the blurb per Goodreads:

In search of the gemstones, deep in the salt caverns of the island of Dramidja...
The wolf-shaman Mika, the enchanted princess, the faithful TamTur and the brave companions, all frozen in time...
Meanwhile...a certain little harpy and two intrepid werewolves join together in a quest to uncover the secret of tehir heritage, and to break the curse of the kingdom...
Return to the land of Greyhawk, where the demon Maelfesh is up to his usual unusual mischief, where magic abides and danger rules, where the beleaguered Wolf Nomad Mika must defeat yet another incredible array of other-worldly sinister forces--the deep-dwelling cavernquatch, the granite moles, the rock beasites and more...

[Note: Typos in source; I'll clean them up if I can find a canonical source instead]
Mika only shows up from book three on, and the harpy isn't met until book four, so this must be close to when you started reading.

Surprised that someone named Maelfesh is not being an upstanding member of society. Must be the influence of his close friend Baddy McEvil.

There is more stuff set in the Greyhawk world availalble. It was the main D&D world created by Gary Gygax and has been used by TSR and later Wizards of the Coast in numerous games. There are a whole bunch of novels by Gary Gygax, Rose Estes and many others.
